# Unable to generate migrations in Django 1.11

Tags: mysql, django

On a blank MySQL database, I generated migrations for a Django 1.11 project with:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I have several custom inter-dependent apps, but all the migrations generated without error. However, when I tried to apply these migrations with:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

it applies most app migrations just fine, but with some custom FeinCMS migrations with:

```
  Applying page.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 93, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 101, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/myproject/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't say which foreign key wasn't generated, and the migration has several. I tried commenting out each field in the migration re-running it, but the migration succeeds when I do it that way.

Why is this migration failing and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in Django created tables that table does not have `INNODB ENGINE`.

In MySql If table has `INNODB ENGINE` that can make relation as foreign key otherwise Django will return error as mentioned in question

```
"django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')"
```

I have solution for this issue.
Firstly create new management command file like name "convert_to_innodb"

and add code as below in that management command file

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.db import connections


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, database="default", *args, **options):
        cursor = connections[database].cursor()
        cursor.execute("SHOW TABLE STATUS")
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            if row[1] != "InnoDB":
                print "Converting %s" % row[0],
                print cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE %s ENGINE=INNODB" % row[0])
```

and RUN command in terminal

```
python manage.py convert_to_innodb
```

After this command execution you can make foreign key in already created table but

```
'OPTIONS': {
   'init_command': 'SET default_storage_engine=INNODB',
}
```

add this configuration in DATABASE settings like below

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': 'SET default_storage_engine=INNODB',
         }
    }
}
```

This db configuration will create next time `INNODB ENGINE` table that will work for future without errors

Comment: Thanks for this writeup, but I don't think this was the issue. My database was already InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Because of a bad merge, there were some errors in previous migrations, causing a disconnect between older migrations and the columns in my models. I fixed this by:

1. deleting all my migrations
2. truncating my `django_migrations` table
3. running `manage.py makemigrations`

Then `migrate` worked.